# how to make datepicker image enable after making it disable in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i make datepicker image clickable/enable after makin it disable like this

```
 $("#_ctl0_MainContent_txtFromDateTime").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Please Select Date",
    onSelect: function() {
        //            $(this).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "MM d yy")
        $("#_ctl0_MainContent_hdnFromDateTime").val($(this).val());
    }
});
$("#_ctl0_MainContent_txtFromDateTime").datepicker('disable');
```

if i use

```
  $("#_ctl0_MainContent_txtFromDateTime").datepicker('enable');
```

it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i enabled datapicker after making it disable.
Firstly i loaded whole datapicker after that enable it

```
 $("#_ctl0_MainContent_txtFromDateTime").datepicker({
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif",
buttonImageOnly: true,
buttonText: "Please Select Date",
onSelect: function() {
    //            $(this).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "MM d yy")
    $("#_ctl0_MainContent_hdnFromDateTime").val($(this).val());
}
```

});

```
 $("#_ctl0_MainContent_txtFromDateTime").datepicker('disable');
```

Made it disable like this.And after that

```
  var disabled = $("#_ctl0_MainContent_txtFromDateTime").datepicker("option", "disabled");
    //setter
    $("#_ctl0_MainContent_txtFromDateTime").datepicker("option", "disabled", false);
    $("#_ctl0_MainContent_txtFromDateTime").datepicker({ constrainInput: true });
    $("#_ctl0_MainContent_txtFromDateTime").datepicker("enable");
```

Answer (score 0):

use settime out for date

```
$.validator.addMethod("endDate", function(value, element) { 

    var startDate = $('#txt_reg_form').val(), 
    ret = Date.parse(startDate) <= Date.parse(value) || value == ""; 

    if(!ret){ /*IF NOT VALID DATE*/

        /*TRY DISABLING DATEPICKER FOR A MOMENT*/
        $("#txt_reg_form").datepicker('disable');

        /*SET TIMEOUT TO ENABLE IT AFTER 1 SECOND*/
        setTimeout(function(){
               $("#txt_reg_form").datepicker('enable');
           }, 1000);
    }
    return ret;
 }
, "To date should be greater then From date"
);
```

Comment: <img src='someimage.gif' id="datepickerImage" />
<div id="datepicker"></div>

add this it will work
$("#datepickerImage").click(function() {
       $("#datepicker").show(); 
    });

Comment: thanks for reply.. but how could i add                              <img src='someimage.gif' id="datepickerImage" /> <div id="datepicker"></div> as i am unable to create its id

Comment: first try with settimeout function.

Comment: on different button or on date button.

Comment: on different button... firstly i made it disable and on clicking on edit button i want to make it enable so that date can be selected from it.

Comment: make that text box realonly and then use datepicker